# creating gtalk type app using django

Tags: python, django, xmpp, instant-messaging

I am learning Python and Django. I want to create a Gtalk type of application using Django and Python. Please tell me where I can find documentation that will help me build my application. Mainly I want to know how to determine when anyone logs in if their friends is online, busy, offline, etc. I also would like to know how to respond to those events. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you can start with learning the [XMPP](http://xmpp.org/) protocol, or learning to use [any of the python libraries that deal with XMPP](http://xmpppy.sourceforge.net/).

I referred you to XMPP because this is the protocol used by GTalk. there are other instant messaging protocols that can be used.

Answer (score 0):

If you're thinking of writing a Gtalk-type application in Django, you could look to host it on Google AppEngine, which has [great support for XMPP](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/using_xmpp.html).

Also, check out [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/), which is better for real-time Python apps than Django is.